# Structured data for FAQ page?

Tags: structured-data, schema.org, microformats

Which structured data (e.g., Microformats or Schema.org) should I use for page with FAQ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The vocabulary Schema.org has the types [`Question`](http://schema.org/Question) and [`Answer`](http://schema.org/Answer) (added in [version 1.1](http://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v1.1) from 2014-04-04).

This is not only [for Q&A sites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/72692/17633), but also for FAQs, as `Question` explicitly mentions (bold emphasis mine):

> A specific question - e.g. from a user seeking answers online, or **collected in a Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ) document**.

Comment: And as [Christian Zagarskas notes in his answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/102633/17633), for the page itself you can use the `QAPage` type.

Answer (score 10):

There is this: https://schema.org/QAPage

and these: https://schema.org/Question + https://schema.org/Answer

Which you can indeed use …

and validate: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

To build your own FAQ page.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
  <h1 itemprop="text">What does FAQ stand for?</h1>
  <div itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
    <p itemprop="text">
    A: Frequently Asked Questions
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Don't use QAPage markup for FAQ pages or pages where there are multiple questions per page. QAPage markup is for pages where the focus of the page is a single question and its answers." https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/qapage

Comment: I feel like you are confusing these. Try this: build a QApage as specified in the example above and as per Google's schema SPEC, then, submit that page to Google Search console, take a look at what google indexes on that page. Try it both ways, see which one gives you an error and which one "validates" as structured data. IMPORTANT: do this via the SEARCH CONSOLE, not just the "testing tool". After that, then take a look at how Google handles your page in SERP, within search results. (you'll see what im saying when you get a page 1 FAQ SERP)

Answer (score 3):

There is no schema entry for FAQ, you most likely best of adding it as a '[WebPage](http://schema.org/WebPage)'. or using the about. It's not required to use rich snippets for all pages. It holds little SEO weight if any. Google will be able to establish it as a FAQ page without any markup of this type.

Comment: For anyone on this page as of 2017- maybe pre 2013 Simon's comment was true... but there is indeed a SCHEMA intended for Q/A pages... run any StackOverflow or stackexchange Q/A through https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool and it will become clear...

Comment: True... Schema has different versions. Latest is Schema Version 3.4

Answer (score 1):

As of end August 2017 the [FAQPage](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1723) type was added to schema.org. It is a subtype of QAPage with the difference that each question has only one answer.

In the spring of 2019 the feature was added to [google search](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/05/new-in-structured-data-faq-and-how-to.html) and is supported by the [Rich Results](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) Tool.