# How to display other pages from my site in the Google search results list how many answers each has?

Tags: seo, google, search-results

I was googling and I faced with this:

[image]

I've searched in the DOM of that page, those links which are listed in the google under that question are all in that page. But how google knows should select those links in the page? Anyway, I want to know, should I use any meta for that?

Also the strange part is, google knows each question from that list has how many answers (highlighted using orange-color). How google knows that? Does Stackoverflow done any specific thing? Or does it used any meta tag?

Comment: Maybe [Structured data for FAQ page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/46881/structured-data-for-faq-page)

Answer (score 1):

That's called [Structured Data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data).

> Structured data is a standardized format for providing information
>   about a page and classifying the page content; for example, on a
>   recipe page, what are the ingredients, the cooking time and
>   temperature, the calories, and so on

You can check in [Google Structure Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?hl=es#url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2432764%2Fchange-the-uri-url-for-a-remote-git-repository) the structured data they are using to help the searchers find the relevant information. In this case, they are using:

- http://schema.org/Answer
- http://schema.org/Question
- http://schema.org/QAPage

The one you are referring to must be **Answer Schema** (it has 10 items).

[image]