# Implementing structured data for FAQ/QA, getting hit with “Exactly one Question expected on page for QAPage” warning

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool

I am trying to implement a Q&A section for my recipe blog post based on [the directions here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/46881/structured-data-for-faq-page).

As it is with every FAQ, I have several questions and answers, but structured data testing tools complains that

> Exactly one `Question` expected on page for `QAPage`.
>
> [image]

[Here’s the structured data testing link](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alittlebitofspice.com%2Fno-bake-choco-marie-biscuit-cake-recipe). The blog post link is also part of that.

How can I resolve this to incorporate multiple questions and answers in a FAQ structured data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`QAPage`](https://schema.org/QAPage) type represents a page with **a single question** (whether it’s a Q&A site like Stack Overflow, or a site’s FAQ section where each question has its own page):

> A `QAPage` is a `WebPage` focussed on a specific `Question` and its `Answer`(s), e.g. in a question answering site or documenting Frequently Asked Questions (FAQs).

For a FAQ page with one or **multiple questions**, you can use the [`FAQPage`](https://pending.schema.org/FAQPage) type:

> A `FAQPage` is a `WebPage` presenting one or more "Frequently asked questions" (see also `QAPage`).

But note that the `FAQPage` type is currently in Pending, i.e., it’s a draft. If you don’t want to use terms from Pending, you  could use the parent type `WebPage` instead.

Related questions on Stack Overflow:

- [Schema.org for the FAQ page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48581089/1591669)
- [QAPage with multiple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52036463/1591669)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because that schema is for page with a single question (e.g., a single question page on Quora or Stack Exchange).

> A QAPage is a WebPage focussed on a specific Question and its Answer(s), e.g. in a question answering site...

Use the [Question schema](https://schema.org/Question) instead.

Comment: Can I use a Question and Answer without any covering element?

Comment: Each question can be a stand-alone element on the page. You can use it in conjunction with `QAPage`, which never actually defines any individual questions or answers. The Rich Snippet Testing tool may give you a warning if you go this route, as `QAPage` is not yet recognized as an official schema.